# What is a Regex check for a valid SQL Server LIKE Expression?

Tags: c#, sql-server, regex

Can anyone think of anything wrong with this check for a valid SQL Server Like expression? I guess maybe the last group is redundant as it is covered by the third group. Anyway - suggestions or improvements welcome.

```
^(\S*%\S*|\S*_\S*|\S*\[\S+\]\S*|\S*\[^\S+\]\S*)$
```

I'm referencing this as my guide:
[Microsoft Docs for SQL Server LIKE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Here are the tests I've written:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void SqlLikeIsValidSqlLikeTest()
    {
        Assert.IsTrue("123%456".IsValidSqlLike());
        Assert.IsTrue("%123456".IsValidSqlLike());
        Assert.IsTrue("123456%".IsValidSqlLike());
        Assert.IsTrue("123_456".IsValidSqlLike());
        Assert.IsTrue("_123456".IsValidSqlLike());
        Assert.IsTrue("123456_".IsValidSqlLike());
        Assert.IsTrue("1_23%456".IsValidSqlLike());
        Assert.IsTrue("123%45_6".IsValidSqlLike());
        Assert.IsTrue("123%456".IsValidSqlLike());
        Assert.IsTrue("12[34]56".IsValidSqlLike());
        Assert.IsTrue("123[1-2]456".IsValidSqlLike());
        Assert.IsTrue("123[1234]456".IsValidSqlLike());
        Assert.IsTrue("123[^1234]456".IsValidSqlLike());
        Assert.IsTrue("[1234]456".IsValidSqlLike());
        Assert.IsTrue("123[1234]".IsValidSqlLike());
        Assert.IsTrue("123[^1-4]456".IsValidSqlLike());
        Assert.IsTrue("[^1-4]456".IsValidSqlLike());
        Assert.IsTrue("123[^1-4]".IsValidSqlLike());
        Assert.IsTrue("12[3-]56".IsValidSqlLike());
        Assert.IsTrue("12[^]56".IsValidSqlLike());
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void SqlLikeIsNotValidSqlLikeTest()
    {
        Assert.IsFalse("123456".IsValidSqlLike());
        Assert.IsFalse("12[3456".IsValidSqlLike());
        Assert.IsFalse("1234]56".IsValidSqlLike());
        Assert.IsFalse("12]34[56".IsValidSqlLike());
        Assert.IsFalse("]34[56".IsValidSqlLike());
        Assert.IsFalse("34[^56".IsValidSqlLike());
        Assert.IsFalse("12]34[".IsValidSqlLike());
        Assert.IsFalse("12[]56".IsValidSqlLike());
    }
```

Comment: SQL Server doesn't support Regex. It uses an expression that does contain some similarities to Regex, but it is quite far from it in functionality. I can't read Regex I'm afraid, however, if you explain what you're trying to achieve here, I'll be happy to try and provide a SQL `LIKE` expression that'll work for your needs.

Comment: @Larnu - the question is not about using a regex expression in SQL, but about using regex to check that an SQL Like clause is valid.

Comment: Rather than showing us that hideous regex, can you show us data which it is supposed to be matching?

Comment: What do you mean check if a SQL `LIKE` clause is valid? Where are you, therefore, doing your Regex check? Can you elaborate on your scenario please.

Comment: What makes a like expression invalid?

Comment: @PaulF May i suggest you update the question be more clear, and also to include examples of text that you want to "approve" + examples of text that you want to "disapprove" using your regex.

Comment: @PeterB - it is not my question to update, I was clarifying what OP was asking. All I would update is removing the C# tag.

Comment: As far as anything wrong with the regex - it doesn't appear to allow expressions with no wildcard characters & it doesn't appear to allow for multiple wildcard characters (other than the \S will eat up any after the first) & it doesn't allow for any whitespace characters. Also the expression needs surrounding with single/double quotes.

Comment: Wouldn't the use of a Sql parser be enought to check if the like part is correct ? Because Ms has using Microsoft.Data.Schema.ScriptDom.Sql; T sql parser if needed

Comment: `LIKE <x>` is valid for any `<x>` that is a valid T-SQL string expression. You will never get an error for any string fed to a `LIKE` clause, it will just not match what you're expecting if you "get it wrong" (but you don't know if matching `a-z]%` isn't exactly what the user wanted, instead of being a typo for `[a-z]%`). Your check for validity is either unnecessary, or should be constrained by business concerns, not based on pure syntax.

Comment: This isn't part of the question, but some people have said they can't read regex. If you go to https://regex101.com/ and paste in a regex expression it will tell you what it is doing. You might find that helpful in future if you need to figure out a regex expression.

Comment: Rejecting `123456` is particularly problematic. There should be no prohibition on using `LIKE` to match exact values, because that's the sort of thing that system could generate automatically, and SQL Server certainly has no problem with it. Conversely, a pattern like `[]]` is accepted by your check even though that's not a valid pattern for matching purposes (it doesn't match anything, not even `]`). It's really unclear what you're trying to *achieve* with this check -- why not leave the filtering to SQL Server?

Comment: I need to check that it is a patterned like - not the same as a plain equals - so any valid SQL Server pattern that can be used by a LIKE. But I hadn't realised []] was a special case - thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Just to note that my question was asking if anyone had a better RegEx to do this and so far no one has. I think it is clear what I want - a check that there is a valid SQL Server pattern used by LIKE. If there is no pattern match the RegEx should return a false. So although it is true that LIKE 'abc' won't error, it is the same as = 'abc' and hence not a pattern match.

Answer (score 0):

**This may not the exact solution you may be looking for**, but a way around to solve your problem.

If you have an SQL connection, you can avoid the need to write an SQL parser, by using the "**SET NOEXEC ON**" command before executing your SQL command. This tells SQL not to execute any commands, just evaluate if they would have been executed.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SET NOEXEC ON", conn);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlToBeChecked, conn);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

If no exception is thrown, all is fine.

Or here are the other ways to do 
[Query Validation using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6287851/query-validation-using-c-sharp)

Hope it will help you

Comment: I did see the SQL parser answer but it seemed too much for what I wanted. Also I'm working with services and would need to make a call to the service to run the SQL on the service then get the result, whereas I'm sure I can do what I want with a regex expression.

It is just I'm no expert at regex and while I believe this works (I've written some tests which run ok)  I'd appreciate some confirmation.