# Validate SQL queries and result sets

Tags: sql, c#-4.0, azure, amazon-web-services, azure-sql-database

I am working on an education project for students to test their skills on SQL;
we create some questions and ask students to solve them.

The problem comes here:

1. How do I create SQL questions? I mean, suppose I asked a student to create a table with some constraints and data types, where is this table going to be created?  In my production database? I guess not; if I exposed my database to enduser [evils], they will try to damage it.
2. How do I validate the result sets `[Create/Alter/Insert/Update/Rename]`?
3. How can I establish isolation for answers for different users?

I don't know how [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) handles these scenarios, but my requirement is the same as SQL Fiddle.

I found [Validation of Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276035/code-to-validate-sql-scripts) but this specific to SQL Server, and my question is not restricted to one platform (DBMS).

Comment: Why not just use SQL Fiddle?  Also, if you're curious as to how SQL Fiddle does something, feel free to take a look at my source on GitHub - it's all out there: https://github.com/jakefeasel/sqlfiddle

Comment: i don't know there is support by you,API ?

Comment: What do you need to provide that isn't available simply from the UI?  Surely you could just give your students links to a started schema fiddle (something like http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a2581 ) and then have them send you links back with their completed query.

Comment: i appreciate your suggestion,but i am restricted on this,

Comment: That's unfortunate.  See my answer for a suggestion on building it yourself.  You might consider cloning a copy of sql fiddle and running it locally for this problem, if building your own app is too much to expect.

Comment: Jake Feasel thanks, by your answer i got some insight. how to proceed, sorry i don't know cold fusion.  :)

Comment: I doubt you'd really need to modify any of the CF code, and you don't need to know it at all to get it running locally - just see the readme on github. It's pretty straightforward MVC stuff.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21699/discussion-between-joshua-and-jake-feasel)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking to provide a free-form window into your SQL server that allows students to execute queries but not destroy the database (as SQL Fiddle does), then the simplest thing to do is to build a webapp that takes their SQL as input and runs it within a transaction.  Capture the result sets from each query as you execute it.  After executing each of their SQL statements, roll back the transaction; none of their changes will then be committed to the server.

If you suspect your students are incredibly mischievous and will stop at nothing to break the database (as I have with SQL Fiddle users), then you will have to guard against explicit transaction commits, such as `commit transaction;`.  Guarding against this is highly database-specific; I recommend looking [through my code on github](https://github.com/jakefeasel/sqlfiddle) to see how I protect the various databases for SQL Fiddle (hint - the easiest server to protect is PostgreSQL; use it if you can).  You may also find it interesting to read through my question on dba.se on the subject of preventing explicit commits: [Disable explicit commits in JDBC, detect them in SQL, or put the database in a readonly state](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/18971/5074)

Comment: Although is *all* DDL transaction-safe? Linked execution? Preventing unwanted transactions? Somehow I think that this might not be "safe" enough .. also, don't forget DOS/resource attacks.

Comment: @pst - It is highly database specific.  Here's a good article comparing transactional ddl in various databases: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Transactional_DDL_in_PostgreSQL:_A_Competitive_Analysis .  Preventing resource attacks is also vendor specific: MS SQL uses a cost governor; Oracle has resource limits for a profile; others have to simply use a connection timeout.

Comment: (My point is the initial paragraph in this reply is not sufficient and glosses over many issues and implies some "safety"; it is first but not as important as the rest.)

Comment: @pst yes there are a lot of potential things to consider.  This is really why my first suggestion (in comments) was for him to use SQL Fiddle.  Second, it was for him to build a local copy of sql fiddle (for some reason directly using it isn't an option).  There are a lot of issues to deal with in this realm that I've already tried to address in my app.