# Code to Validate SQL SELECT Statement Script

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server

How can I validate SELECT statements, without executing using .Net and C#?

If the sql is not valid or if the sql is other operation than SELECT (example: alter, insert, delete, ...) I want to return error rows.

This question is very much like: [Code to validate SQL Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3276035/1233788).  But I'm not want to accept any sql script. I want to accept only SELECT statements.

Answer (score 2):

Begin the statement with `SET NOEXEC ON`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188394.aspx

Comment: Thanks for help but this solve the SQL script validation. How to solve my question about SELECT? I want to validate ONLY select statements.

Comment: You could check it as per SverreN's answer, but that could be pretty unsafe. Better would be to check it as per this answer, and only ever run it under a very limited SQL user account which only had SELECT permissions.

Comment: Thinking outside the box, you could ensure that the user is a read only user. Then they can never update data. Don't rely in manual parsing to exclude data changes. They could run a stored procedure that performs updates/inserts and you wouldn't know.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Regular Expression to check it:
    `regex = "SELECT [*] FROM [*]"`

Comment: Good idea, but would have to be really careful that the regex used didn't allow injection vectors like comments and so on.